# Convert NSDate from AVDateRangeMetadataGroup to CMTime

Tags: avfoundation, avplayer, http-live-streaming

`AVPlayer` primarily measures times with `CMTime`. However when using an `AVPlayerItemMetadataCollector` to collect date range metadata from an HLS stream, the resulting `AVDateRangeMetadataGroup`s hold `NSDate`s instead of `CMTime`s.

My problem is I want to add a boundary time observer to the player so I know when the playback head actually enters the date range, but you can only add a boundary time observer using `CMTime`. `AVPlayer` and `AVPlayerItem` can seek to a `Date` and can give me the current playback head as a `Date`, but I don't see any way to convert a given `Date` into a `CMTime` that I can use to set a boundary time observer.

In theory if I knew what the `EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME` tag said I could calculate a `CMTime` offset myself, but I don't see a way to retrieve that.

The only other thought I had was to retrieve both `currentTime` and `currentDate` from the `AVPlayerItem`, then calculate the relative offset between `currentDate` and my target date and apply that to the `CMTime`. But a problem with this solution is the `currentDate` and `currentTime` won't represent the exact same time. The delta is presumably going to be very small, but it won't be zero (unless the `rate` itself is zero).

Comment: I would also accept any recommendation for how to know when `currentDate` becomes non-`nil`, because if I can read that as soon as it becomes available initially, that will presumably be before I'm actually playing the stream and therefore the effective rate will be zero.

Comment: It's also worth noting that if the stream includes any discontinuous media segments, trying to calculate a time using `currentDate` and `currentTime` won't be reliable (as that won't know about the discontinuity).

Comment: Do you have any code to show or any minimum working project examples to try? How about setting a property observer on a variable which would trigger a print statement once that is being set using a get and set ??

Comment: `currentDate` has no setter, so there's nothing to override. It's a computed property, based on both `currentTime` and on internal data that isn't exposed to the user (namely, a time<->date mapping based on `EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME` tags from the media playlists with no API to query it).

Comment: I've hit the same issue. I was going down the route of matching `currentTime` and `currentDate`. I'm curious how you know that the `currentTime` and `currentDate` do not represent the same time? I am seeing this from experimentation, but I didn't expect this. Also, did you ever manage to find a solution? 

(P.S. Your issue SR-6795 on Swift KVO and swizzling saved me potentially days of headache tracking the cause of a random crash, so thank you for that).